Need clarification about TFT LCD technology
I’ve been researching to get a general understanding of the main LCD technologies.
From what I’ve gathered, if I were to summarize briefly, LCD technology relies on the control of liquid crystals. There are three main types: TN, IPS, and VA. Each has its own advantages and disadvantages, with the primary difference being how the liquid crystals are oriented.
In addition, there’s TFT technology, which allows control over each sub-pixel (R, G, and B) using transistors.
So far, I hope my understanding is correct.
I have a few questions:

Before the advent of TFT, were they able to control a matrix of liquid crystals with sub-pixel precision? If so, how was it achieved? Was it done using vertical and horizontal electrodes?
Regarding TFT, are both the transistors and the liquid crystal layer electrodes used to control the pixels, or just the transistors? What is the advantage of using transistors in this case?
From my understanding, TN, IPS, and VA only influence how the liquid crystals are oriented. Therefore, I would assume that TFT is an additional technology applied to these, meaning we get TN TFT LCD, IPS TFT LCD, and VA TFT LCD. Is this correct? It’s not entirely clear, as I often see “TFT LCD” without any mention of TN, IPS, or VA.


To add to @Marcus Müller 's excellent answer: In practice, the biggest change was TFT. Before you couldn't track your mouse on an LCD screen because the update time was ridiculously slow. "Sub Pixel" sounds like marketing double speak. Link to a good definition in your question if you think it's not. As for everything else, these appear to be variations to improve contrast and viewing angle. I suspect everything made now uses TFT. The only exception I can think of are privacy panels where a slow change might be desirable.


Before the advent of TFT, were they able to control a matrix of liquid crystals with sub-pixel precision? If so, how was it achieved? Was it done using vertical and horizontal electrodes?

"subpixel" is a concept that doesn't apply to the LCD: to the LCD, the red, green and blue dots are just pixels. Their color comes from a colored filter stacked in front. So, yes, any colored graphical display has this precision.
However, colored graphical displays at modern resolutions are mostly possible through TFT only, so, there's that "in theory yes, in practice any colored LCD display with pixels that you can buy will be a TFT display".

Regarding TFT, are both the transistors and the liquid crystal layer electrodes used to control the pixels, or just the transistors? What is the advantage of using transistors in this case?

this question makes no sense. Can you steer your car without the front wheels? Can you steer your car without a steering wheel? You need both for the kind of car we build today.
The transistor controls the voltage at the electrode.

Therefore, I would assume that TFT is an additional technology applied to these, meaning we get TN TFT LCD, IPS TFT LCD, and VA TFT LCD.

Yes. TFT just literally means what the abbreviation means: there's transistors on a thin film, which makes it possible to drive the pixels easily, and close to where they are, drastically increasing density and possible contrast compared to passive matrix LCD panels where every pixel has to have its own connection to the edge of the panel.
So, honestly, if it shows color graphics these days and is an LCD, it's a TFT panel.

I would say that if it displays full-colo[u]r graphics and it's not an OLED, it's probably TFT. There are still small passive matrix monochrome LCD displays being sold- eg. 1/64 128 x 64 glass has  64+128 = 192 connections. Some such displays and e-ink (also passive matrix, I think) have some  colour.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany true (though I'd assume OLED panels are technically also based on a TFT matrix)

Yes, AMOLED (active matrix) indeed use thin-film transistors, but the smaller ones often are diode (passive) matrix and use  anode and cathode COG driver dies that have a bizzare aspect ratio, and up to ~2k bonding pads- like a matchstick of silicon.

that is pretty impressive, @Spehro'speff'Pefhany (especially since it means that bonding errors become relatively expensive for something that is probably pretty low-cost)


Before the advent of TFT, were they able to control a matrix of liquid crystals ... Was it done using vertical and horizontal electrodes?

A long time ago LCD panels without TFTs were addressed using only the vertical and horizontal electrodes. In principle you could activate, say, one horizontal electrode and write data onto the vertical electrodes. This did not scale well because of the existence of sneak paths that partially activated pixels along other horizonatal electrodes. TFTs were a game-changer.

A bit of history, monochrome LCD like the one on calculator, 7-segments screen is so called passive LCD. It has upper and lower glasses, with electrode wires. Upper and lower wires are perpendicular to each other. Each segment is controlled by electrodes' crossing point.
Now, we demand more dots on screen. Laying those wires on high resolution screen is impossible. That's why we use TFT (Thin Film Transistor) to control a pixel. You can treat it as a switch. TFT LCD is also called active matrix display. Actually both LCD and OLED use TFT technology.
As for TN, IPS and VA, they are panel types, to do with how liquid crystal twist. To complicate things further, you sometimes hear the terms a-Si, LTPS(iPhone screen) and IGZO. These are related to how transistor is created (silicon).
This TFT Technology post sums up their mix & match, pros and cons.
